# Clearing NSCache in iOS 9.3 does not work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, ios9.3

Facing an issue when clearing objects stored in `NSCache`.
Trying to use:

```
 NSCache.removeAllObjects();
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. I am doing the above using **iOS 9.3**, which came out just this week.

Comment: It's really pathetic experience of iOS 9.3. We need to clear URL response cache also to resolve this issue.